# how to make the relationship between velocity and time be linear by ROS-python

Tags: python-2.7, time, ros, face-detection

I created code which making turtlebot 2 following me depend on detecting my face and chose a value of velocity 0.2 m/s.

my issue is the movement of the robot when disappearing my face suddenly which making turtlebot stops suddenly, I need to make decreasing its velocity gradually like this figure [enter link description here](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=linear%20velocity%20with%20time&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi754nI8_HgAhXCxbwKHRJ3D_gQ_AUIDigB&biw=1855&bih=952#imgrc=fbTRSzhfqRk8uM:)

my experience not good in ROS'time

I need it starting the count the seconds from zero every it lost my face.
my issue in my code, Once run the code, the time increase continuously whether it is lost my face or not.in this line

```
 v = self.twist.linear.x = (-0.07 * t + 0.2)
```

my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python



import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
import cv2, cv_bridge


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/redhwan/1/run-webcam/Face-Detect-Demo-by-Ali-master/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' )


class Face_detection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bridge = cv_bridge.CvBridge()
        self.starting_time = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec()
        self.save_time = True


        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/usb_cam/image_raw',Image, self.image_callback)
        self.cmd_vel_pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop',Twist, queue_size=1)
        self.twist = Twist()


    def image_callback(self, msg):
        image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg,desired_encoding='bgr8')

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale( gray,scaleFactor=1.1,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(30, 30),flags=cv2.cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


            self.twist.linear.x = 0.2

            self.cmd_vel_pub.publish(self.twist)


        cv2.imshow('face ', image)


        cv2.waitKey(3)




        if(type(faces) == tuple):

            if(self.save_time == False):
#                self.save_time = False  #Condition only the first time
                self.starting_time = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec() #save the current time
            now = rospy.get_rostime().to_sec()
#                self.save_time == False
            t = (now - self.starting_time)
            print ('t',t)
            if t <2.9:

                v = self.twist.linear.x = (-0.07 * t + 0.2)
                print v
                self.cmd_vel_pub.publish(self.twist)


            if t >= 2.9:
                v = self.twist.linear.x = 0
                print v
                self.cmd_vel_pub.publish(self.twist)


rospy.init_node('face_detection')
follower = Face_detection()
rospy.spin()
```

please help me

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do it make the movements of turtlebot smoother.  You might find that the [velocity smoother package](http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_velocity_smoother) will fulfill your needs.
You can install it by running: 
`sudo apt install ros-kinetic-yocs-velocity-smoother`
The node takes raw velocity input and filters it based on acceleration parameters. So you can remap your cmd_velocity_mux output to raw_cmd_vel and remap the smoothed output smooth_cmd_vel to the input going to the turlebot.

Comment: thank you so this information, I will use it, this may be another solution

Comment: I installed, my system indigo, `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-indigo-yocs-velocity-smoother is already the newest version.
ros-indigo-yocs-velocity-smoother set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 imagemagick-common libblas-dev libcoin80 libcoin80-dev
  libdjvulibre-dev libdmtx-dev libdmtx0a libexif-dev libfftw3-double3
  libgraphviz-dev libgvc6-plugins-gtk liblapack-dev liblqr-1-0 liblqr-1-0-dev

..
..
` but not change

Comment: not work, `self.cmd_pub = rospy.Publisher("/smooth_cmd_vel", Twist, queue_size=10)`

Comment: those topics are working with me:`/mobile_base/commands/velocity`  , `/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi` ,  `/cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller` & `/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop`

Comment: please see this my question if you can help me, thanks in advance [https://answers.ros.org/question/318914/how-to-make-velocity-of-turtlebot-is-smoother/]